# Dynamically Importing Images Based on a Variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a requirement to select, from a local source, an image based on the value passed back from the REST API I am using. For example:

```js
//Psuedo-call from the API
var imageIdToSelect = response.data.imageId

//Then later in the render()
<img src={ baseUrl + imageIdToSelect } />
```

I have a solution to this, which is to use `require()` as that allows me to append the url as such:

```js
<img src={ require(baseUrl + imageIdToSelect) } />
```

This works fine, however, I am using a Microsoft TSLINT setup that does not allow `require()` over the prefered `import` at the top of the file "`no-require-imports`".

I know I am not meant to let linting tools control my work to the point where I am just blindly following rules. So my question is two-fold:

1. Why is it frowned upon to use `require()` in such a way. One reason I could think of is that if all of the external files/resources are declared at the top of the file, then you don't have to look through the source to find them hidden in functions.
2. What would the `import x from './'` solution look like here? I have seen people creating `index.js` and `index.d.ts` files inside their image folders to import and export all the images inside but that seems a tad extraneous.

Edit: I also have just realised that using `require()` with a non-literal string is a violation of my ts-linting too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `import * as images from "./pathToImgsFolder" `  then images.X

Comment: `ENOENT: no such file or directory` as it is trying to find `./pathToImgsFolder/index.js` when I add your suggestion.

Comment: so, give an example of `baseUrl + imageIdToSelect` I assumed that would be something  like `./public/img/logo.png` but that is searching for JS file

Comment: Well it is as you expect, but if i just point my `import` to a folder, it searches for an `index.js` file, and wont just read the content